# UIVisualEffectView not working above UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, blur, uivisualeffectview

I have a `UIVisualEffectView` inside `myView`. `myView` can be dragged around the screen. Also, there are an image and a `UIWebView` in the ViewController.
Above the image everything works fine but when I drag `myView` above the `UIWebView`, the blur effect does not work anymore and the `myView` just looks like it has a light gray background and is transparent.

[Results from a real iPad Air, iOS 9.2.1]

[image: working blur effect]
*Working (above `UIImage`)*

[image: not working blur effect]
*Not working (above `UIWebView`)*

This is how I create the blur effect:

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight))
blurView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(navView.frame.width, navView.frame.height)
blurView.layer.cornerRadius = navView.layer.cornerRadius
blurView.clipsToBounds = true

let vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView()
vibrancyView.frame = blurView.frame
vibrancyView.effect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurView.effect as! UIBlurEffect)
vibrancyView.layer.cornerRadius = blurView.layer.cornerRadius

blurView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)
vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(left)
vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(right)
myView.addSubview(blurView)
```

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this and try

```
myView.bringSubviewToFront(blurView)
```

or use

```
blurView.superview.bringSubviewToFront(blurView)
```

**Update**

variable creation

```
@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!
```

code

```
  let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight))
    blurView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
    blurView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    blurView.clipsToBounds = true

    let vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView()
    vibrancyView.frame = blurView.frame
    vibrancyView.effect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurView.effect as! UIBlurEffect)
    vibrancyView.layer.cornerRadius = blurView.layer.cornerRadius

    blurView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)
   // vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(left)
    //vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(right)
    webview.addSubview(blurView)

    let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com");
    let myURLRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
    webview.loadRequest(myURLRequest);
```

[image]

I added the [**Sample project**](https://www.sendspace.com/file/e3rf8m)

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: wait i will check an reply

Comment: In your project it works for me too...weird. (Great project name btw. :D)

Comment: One thing about my webView: it loads up a html file rather than a website. But I saw that the blur does not work above a standard `UILabel` as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: Alright, so I checked again and apparently I did add things after adding the blur view so even the `bringToFront` did not work (obviously). Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(UIWebView)
```